# use virtual method of base class C++ in child of child class

Tags: c++, virtual

I've created a class named 'Device' which get inherited by multiple devices (for example, RFDevice, AccelleroDevice)

The Device class inherited a Thread class. This Threadclass includes a Pure virtual function named run. Is it possible to accesss this pure virtual function in RFDevice or AcelleroDevice.

So,

ThreadClass->DeviceClass->RFDeviceClass.

I've tried to add

' virtual void run(void) = 0' also in the device class but this wont work.

Greets,

Comment: Yes, it is possible, provided one of the classes actually provides an implementation. Without seeing what you've tried it's hard to know why it isn't working.

Comment: Can you post the actual code instead of trying to describe it?

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. Code says more than a thousand words.

Answer (score 4):

Only if the virtual function is not private. If it is, then you cannot call it and are not supposed to, either:

```
class ThreadClass
{
public:
    virtual ~ThreadClass() {}
private:
    virtual void run() = 0;
};

class Device : public ThreadClass
{
};

class RFDevice : public Device
{
public:
    void f()
    {
        run(); // compiler error
    }
};
```

If it is protected or public, then it will work, provided there is an implementation of the function somewhere down the class hierarchy. But with the exception of the destructor, virtual functions should rarely be public or protected in C++:

```
class ThreadClass
{
public:
    virtual ~ThreadClass() {}
protected:
    virtual void run() = 0; // non-private virtual, strange
};

class Device : public ThreadClass
{
};

class RFDevice : public Device
{
protected:
    virtual void run()
    {
    }

public:

    void f()
    {
        run(); // works
    }
};
```

Of course, this does not technically call the base function. And that's a good thing; you'd end up with a pure virtual function call otherwise, and your program would crash.

Perhaps what you need to do is to just implement the private virtual function. That would be the preferred class design:

```
class ThreadClass
{
public:
    virtual ~ThreadClass() {}
    void execute()
    {
        run();
    }
private:
    virtual void run() = 0;
};

class Device : public ThreadClass
{
};

class RFDevice : public Device
{
private:
    virtual void run()
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    RFDevice d;
    d.execute();
}
```

If you are not just maintaining a legacy code base, you should probably get rid of your thread class and use [C++11 multi-threading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread).

Comment: Thanks! this was what i was looking for;) Why isnt it a proper way to declare a virtual function protected or public btw?

Comment: @ReinierHasper: This old article by Herb Sutter is still a good resource for this question: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm. Basically, the problem with public virtual functions is that they mix client concerns with implementation concerns.